# Under some circumstances an App Engine "get_by_key_name" call using an existing key_name returns None

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I've run into a strange problem that I haven't seen before making a `get_by_key_name` call using the App Engine ORM.

Under no circumstances, one would assume, would the following return None:

```
Model.get_by_key_name(Model.all().get().key().name())
```

And yet, that's what I've found that certain key names will do. It's only in a few cases where I'm using Open ID URLs like the following as key_name attributes:

```
https://me.yahoo.com/a/jadjuh3s0klsghiLhtBNbIiHw8k-#3dcl3
```

(I've changed a couple of chars to protect the innocent)

Maybe the '#' symbol?

> **Solution: As Nick Johnson suggested, I needed to modify the query since the
>   entity has a parent:**
>
> ```
> entity = Model.all().get()
> Model.get_by_key_name(entity.key().name(), parent=entity.parent_key())
> ```

Whatever the case may be, if there is a circumstance where a key name can't be used to fetch an entity, then it shouldn't be allowed to be used as a key name in the first place.

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, I've had some of these entities for a while without any problem. Perhaps in one of the latest SDK releases this bug was introduced. I know that there has been changes to allow things like key_names starting with integers, and so forth, so perhaps this bug was recently introduced.

Comment: I've filed this as an issue: 
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2228

Comment: Also tried refreshing the datastore and datastore history, and I've ensured that it only affects a single model. There is a single layer of inheritance, but it's not affecting any of the other inherited models, so that doesn't seem to be the root of the problem.

Comment: +1 "if there is a circumstance where a key name can't be used to fetch an entity, then it shouldn't be allowed to be used as a key name in the first place."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model.get_by_key_name(Model.all().get().key().name()) will fail iff the entity returned by the query is a child entity of some other entity. get_by_key_name without a parent parameter looks for an entity with no parents, while the query can return a child entity.

For example:

```
a = Model1()
a.put()
b = Model2(parent=a)
b.put()
Model2.get_by_key_name(Model2.all().get().key().name()) # Fails to return anything
Model2.get(Model2.all().get().key()) # Works as expected
```

Comment: This solved it. And now that I look at the docs again, it's right there. 

Thanks for the help. Hopefully this answer will help other people who run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

out of curiosity, do you see this in production, or in the sdk, or both?

i tried to reproduce it with your example key name in http://shell.appspot.com/ , but couldn't:

```
>>> class Foo(db.Expando):
  pass
>>> Foo(key_name='https://me.yahoo.com/a/jadjuh3s0klsghiLhtBNbIiHw8k-#3dcl3').put()
datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Foo', u'https://me.yahoo.com/a/jadjuh3s0klsghiLhtBNbIiHw8k-#3dcl3', _app_id_namespace=u'shell')
>>> Foo.get_by_key_name('https://me.yahoo.com/a/jadjuh3s0klsghiLhtBNbIiHw8k-#3dcl3')
<__main__.Foo object at 0x75f9c1aa9181d78>
```

(granted, i'm not using your model class hierarchy, which you implied might be what's triggering it.)

Comment: This doesn't ordinarily happen. It's very weird that it's only happening with one model, and as I said, there's nothing distinct about how I'm implementing this model. It only inherits from a db.Model subclass that has some utility methods...and that's never caused a problem before.

I'll test it out on production and update again soon.

Comment: On production it behaves the exact same way, working with all models except for this one specific model, and only with entities that I've recently created. 

The model is called "Pledge", but that really shouldn't make a difference I'd assume.

Comment: And to be clear once again, I've discovered that this behavior occurs regardless of what key name I'm using.