# Getting a list of child entities in App Engine using get_by_key_name (Python)

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, model

My adventures with entity groups continue after a slightly embarrassing beginning (see [Under some circumstances an App Engine `get_by_key_name` call using an existing key_name returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535114)).

I now see that I can't do a normal `get_by_key_name` call over a list of entities for child entities that have more than one parent entity. As the Model docs say,

> Multiple entities requested by one
>   (`get_by_key_name`) call must all have
>   the same parent.

I've gotten into the habit of doing something like the following:

```
# Model just has the basic properties
entities = Model.get_by_key_name(key_names)
# ContentModel has all the text and blob properties for Model
content_entities = ContentModel.get_by_key_name(content_key_names)

for entity, content_entity in zip(entities, content_entities):
 # do some stuff
```

Now that ContentModel entities are children of Model entities, this won't work because of the single-parent requirement.

An easy way to enable the above scenario with entity groups is to be able to pass a list of parents to a `get_by_key_name` call, but I'm guessing that there's a good reason why this isn't currently possible. I'm wondering if this is a hard rule (as in there is absolutely no way such a call could ever work) or if perhaps the db module could be modified so that this type of call would work, even if it meant a greater CPU expense.

I'd also really like to see how others accomplish this sort of task. I can think of a bunch of ways of handling it, like using GQL queries, but none I can think of approach the performance of a `get_by_key_name` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a key list and do a get on it.

```
entities = Model.get_by_key_name(key_names)
content_keys = [db.Key.from_path('Model', name, 'ContentModel', name) 
                for name in key_names]
content_entities = ContentModel.get(content_keys)
```

Note that I assume the key_name for each ContentModel entity is the same as its parent Model.  (For a 1:1 relationship, it makes sense to reuse the key_name.)

Comment: Great idea. I don't make use of db.Key.from_path nearly enough.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm embarrassed to say that the restriction ('must be in the same entity group') actually no longer applies in this case. Please do feel free to [file](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) a documentation bug!

In any case, get_by_key_name is only syntactic sugar for get, as Bill Katz illustrates. You can go a step further, even, and use db.get on a list of keys to get everything in one go - db.get doesn't care about model type.

Comment: If you're getting more than one child entity and attempt to pass a list for parent, it returns a BadArgumentError since it won't accept a list of keys. 

So unless you can pass a list of parent keys, it seems like the restriction is still in place.

Comment: A list for parent? No, that obviously won't work - you need to construct key objects and use db.get() on them. I wasn't aware you were attempting to get child entities.